# yii2 anchor tag from fronend to backend

Tags: yii2

I have an application where the signup form is at the frontend folder while the login is at the backend.

Then i have this menu...

```
    //sends the browser to frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fsignup
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];

    //sends the browser to frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
```

I want the second link to be link to `backend/web/index.php?r=site/login`

here is the urlManager

```
'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/ncddp/backend/web',
            // here is your backend URL rules
        ],
        'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '/ncddp/frontend/web',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],  //end of url manager
```

I don't know how to use this url manager.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1578

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative path

```
'url' => ['../../../frontend/web/index.php?r=site/login']
```

and this is my urlManager configuration

```
    'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => true, 
    ],
```

In this way in my application the relative path work correctly

Comment: this returns `http://localhost/ncddp/frontend/web/index.php?r=..%2F..%2F..%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Findex.php%3Fr%3Dsite%2Flogin`

Comment: Please post your urlManager configuration you can find it in config\main.php or config\main-local.php

Comment: I don't know a public property named   'urlManagerFrontEnd'. I can't find  it in Yii2 api docs.   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html  . Try without 'urlManagerFrontEnd'  configuration element.

Comment: actually i have added it manually. If I delete it what should I do next?